# Display node in user profile page

Tags: theming, users, nodes

I created a content type called `successful story`.

In user profile page `user-profile.tpl.php`, I have inserted a link to create a `successful story`

```
<?php print l(t('Add a successful story'), "node/add/successful-story"); ?>
```

For example, an user called `user1` clicks on the link, and creates a successful story. 
**I want to display the successful story the user created into their respective profile page**

I add this code into `template.php`

```
<?php

function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type", array(":uid" => $uid, ":type" => 'successful story'))->fetchCol();
  $variables['ss_node'] = drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
}

?>
```

Then I add this code into `user-profile.tpl.php`

```
<?php

  global $user;
  $user_id = arg(1);

print $ss_node;

?>
```

I hope I'm clear. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

It won't be available directly in the template. First you should query the content created by that user and then pass it to template file using preprocess function. Finally render the node.

First to find the node created by the user

```
$nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type", array(":uid" => $uid, ":type" => 'successful_story'))->fetchCol();
```

(Hope the user creates only one node or else you got to check it)

Then get the node content

```
$variables['ss_node'] = drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
```

The final code should be like

```
function template_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  global $user;
  $uid = $user->uid;
  $nid = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type", array(":uid" => $uid, ":type" => 'successful_story'))->fetchCol();
  $variables['ss_node'] = drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nid)));
}
```

Finally you can just print the `$ss_node` in `user-profile.tpl.php`

Comment: I try this, I'll keep you in touch !

Comment: I got this error : Cannot redeclare template_preprocess_page(). I added the function code into template.php

Comment: You shouldn't redeclare template_preprocess_page(), instead add the code inside the already existing template_preprocess_page().

Comment: I added your code into the function in theme.inc file. But I get a bunch of error message. How can I give you the code I wrote ?

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong! You should actually put the code in template.php, replace template_preprocess_page with theme_name_preprocess_page(). Say your theme name is 'mytheme', then it should be mytheme_preprocess_page()

Comment: I did this, then I added print $ss_node; into user-profile.tpl.php. But it does not appear

Comment: Well, did you check as the user who created the node?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33855/discussion-between-corentin-branquet-and-suresh-r).